# Recalculate Total after Order place

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I m trying to recalculate magento total using magento event observer after placing order.I m use below code to calculate total.

Observer Functon

```
public function recalculateTotal($observer){
    //var_dump($observer->getOrder()->getData());exit;
    $orderModel = $observer->getOrder();
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($orderModel->getData());echo "</pre>";exit;
    $saveModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderModel->getId());
    $saveModel->setSurcharge(10);
    $saveModel->setBaseSurcharge(10);
    $saveModel->collectTotals();
    $saveModel->save();
    echo "<pre>";print_r($orderModel->getData());echo "</pre>";exit;
}
```

Event

```
 <global>
    <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
          <observers>
            <order_surcharge_display>
              <type>singleton</type>
              <class>surcharge/observer</class>
              <method>recalculateTotal</method>
            </order_surcharge_display>
          </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
  </events>

</global>
```

But nothing change please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could not recalculate order totals. This method is available only for the quote. You have to use: `sales_quote_collect_totals_after` event in case you want to add your personal values.

In the config.xml of your module you should add something like this to convert your total from the quote to the order:

```
<sales_convert_quote>
    <surcharge_amount>
        <to_order>*</to_order>
    </surcharge_amount>
    <base_surcharge_amount>
        <to_order>*</to_order>
    </base_surcharge_amount>
</sales_convert_quote>
```

Direct change the order totals:

```
public function recalculateTotal($observer){
    //var_dump($observer->getOrder()->getData());exit;
    $orderModel = $observer->getOrder();
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($orderModel->getData());echo "</pre>";exit;
    $orderModel->setSurchargeAmount(10); // usually all totals has "amount" suffix
    $orderModel->setBaseSurchargeAmount(10);
    $orderModel->setGrandTotal($orderModel->getGrandTotal() + 10);
    $orderModel->setBaseGrandTotal($orderModel->getBaseGrandTotal() + 10);
    try {
        $orderModel->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($orderModel->getData());echo "</pre>";exit;
}
```

PS: *You have to make changes in the quote and quote address but not in the order*

Comment: Thanks for your replay @Siarhey But this is not working as i want to change grandtotal after place order.